# regex: match everything until `:` or `(`

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I would like a regex to get everything until the first occurrence of the char `:` OR the char `(`, with an optional space before.

Take this text:

```
foo : bar
foo bar: baz
foo (bar): baz
```

expected:

```
<foo>: bar
<foo bar>: baz
<foo> (bar): baz
```

I tried this `(.*[:\(])`, but this give:

```
<foo :> bar
<foo bar:> baz
<foo (bar):> baz
```

See https://regex101.com/r/sR4hA5/1

I am using Python 3.5.

Any idea?

Comment: How about that `^(.*)[:\(]`

Comment: @JonathanParentLévesque: too greedy.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
^([^:(]+?)(\s*[:(])
```

and replace with `<\1>\2`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uU7vV6/1).

The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^:(]+?)` - Group 1 matching 1 or more characters other than `:` and `(` but as few as possible up to the first...
- `(\s*[:(])` - Group 2: zero or more whitespaces followed with a `:` or `(`.

The lazy quantifier `+?` is required to force the "trailing" spaces fall into Group 2.

[Python 3 demo](http://ideone.com/6FK2pF):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^([^:(]+?)(\s*[:(])', re.MULTILINE)
s = "foo : bar\nfoo bar: baz\nfoo (bar): baz"
result = p.sub(r"<\1>\2", s)
print(result)
```

Comment: I added some explanations. Just found out I failed to rename one variable in the demo, and fixed it. Now, all seems working.

Comment: Just perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`^[^(:]*[^(:\s]`

[image]

This version does not grab the trailing ':' or '\s'